# Array Rotations

Tags: c++, arrays, rotation

So I want to write a C++ program to perform Array Rotations for r times. Now one array rotation means that the first element of the array moves to the last position and all the other elements at the (i)th position move to (i-1)th position.

The issue I am facing is that even though I have applied a forloop for the number of times the rotations should occur, but then too the array rotates just once. Please help on what I am missing on.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i,n,r,arr1[100],arr2[100];
cout<<"Please enter the number of elements in your array: "<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"Please enter the number of rotations to be performed: "<<endl;
cin>>r;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr1[i];
}    
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{   
    arr2[n-1]=arr1[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
       arr2[i-1]=arr1[i];
    }
}
cout<<"Printing now:"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<arr2[i]<<"\t";
}
}
```

Comment: You use same counter for all of your loop...

Comment: `arr2` only depends of unmutated `arr1`. (you do same assignment in a loop, so no extra changes).

Comment: [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Rotate(int arr[], int n, int r){
        /* To get the starting point of rotated array */
        int mod = r % n;
     
        // Prints the rotated array from start position
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << (arr[(mod + i) % n]) << " ";
     
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

Try this code.
You can read more about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-left-rotation-array/)

Answer (score 0):

For someone who wants the whole working code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


void leftRotate(int arr[], int n, int k)
{
/* To get the starting point of rotated array */
int mod = k % n;

// Prints the rotated array from start position
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << (arr[(mod + i) % n]) << " ";

cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
int n,k,arr[100];
cout<<"Please enter the number of elements: "<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"Now enter the elements:"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
}
cout<<"Enter the number of rotations to be performed: "<<endl;
cin>>k;
  

leftRotate(arr, n, k);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ll n,r;
    cin>>n>>r;
    ll a[n];

    /* pre-compute the index where the element would be present after rotation 
       by 'r' times and then insert it in the array */
    for(ll i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ll index = ((n+i)-r)%n;
        cin>>a[index];
    }

    // print the rotated array
    for(ll i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```